# Proving that the derivative exists

Tags: calculus

I have a question regarding the following exercise.

Let $f(x)= \begin{cases} x^n \mbox{ for } x \geq 0\\ 0 \mbox{ for } x<0 \end{cases}$

Show that the iterated derivatives $f^{(1)}$ through $f^{(n-1)}$ exist at all real numbers x, but the n-th iterated derivative at 0 does not.

I was able to prove that the n-th iterated derivative at 0 does not exist: at right of 0, its value is n! and left of 0, its value is 0.

Since the derivative left and right of 0 is different, the n-th iterated derivative is therefore non differentiable in 0.

But can someone show me how to prove that the first to the n-1 derivatives exist?

Thank you

Comment: Have you been taught the epsilon-delta definition of a differentiation? If so, just try to plug it in, using $\displaystyle \frac{x^n-y^n}{x-y} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^iy^{n-1-i}$

Comment: No we did not yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the quotient 
$$\frac{f^{(n-1)}(h+0)-f^{(n-1)}(0)}{h}.$$

- What if $h\to0$ from below (that is $h<0$)?
- What if $h\to0$ from above (that is $h>0$)?

If you wish you might start with $n=1$.

*Edit* For $n=1$ we should look at
$$\frac{f^{(0)}(h+0)-f^{(0)}(0)}{h}=\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h},\tag{1}$$
with $$f(x)=\begin{cases} x \text{ for } x \geq 0\\ 0 \text{ for } x<0 \end{cases}\tag{2}$$ 
Now, substitute (2) into (1). What happens when $h\to0$ for $h<0$ and what happens when $h\to0$ for $h>0$?

Now go for $n=2$, $n=3$, etc. until you see and can explain the general picture.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: @user43418 Is the edit easier?

Comment: If h>0, the quotient equals h and its limit is therefore 0
If h<0, the quotient equals 0

Since the limit left and right of 0 is the same, then $f^{(0)}$ exists.

Comment: And now I suppose it is true for n-2 terms and show that it is true for n-1 right ?

Comment: @user43418 No it is not $h$ for $h>0$.

Answer (score 2):

You would do something very similar. The $k$th derivative would be given by
$$f^{(k)}(x) = \begin{cases} (n)_kx^{n-k} \mbox{ for } x > 0\\ 0 \mbox{ for } x<0 \end{cases}$$
where $(n)_k = n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)$ is the falling factorial. There's no issues away from $0$, but as $x\rightarrow 0$ from the left and the right, do the limits coincide?

Comment: yes I think they do

Comment: I think they do too. But can you prove that they do? I would probably use Newton's quotient explicitly to show that the limits coincide.

Comment: Can you prove it for me. I just did 10 problems of derivatives and this is my last question. Please :(

Comment: That isn't how this site works. I'm sorry. I'd be happy to provide assistance if you show me some progress though.

Comment: So I have to show it to be true for n=1 and then for n terms by induction ?

Comment: Is that correct?

Comment: That's certainly one way to proceed.

Comment: we proceed with induction on k right ?

Comment: I don't understand the notation in the k-th derivative. There is a $n_k$ what does that mean ?

Comment: It's a [falling factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol).

Comment: By $(n)_k$ EuYu means $n!/k!$.

Comment: Ah ok. I understand

Comment: But the induction is on k right ?

Comment: @EuYu I did not know that was a common term, thanks (+1)